# Visual Studio Isolated Shell, issue adding/removing extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, shell, visual-studio-2012

the problem is when I can't change extensions included in a package for visual studio isolated shell after performing a first build.

Shortly speaking. No matter what extensions I add/remove changes are visible only when the project was never build and run before.

Step by step how to reproduce this issue:

1) New Project... -> Visual Studio Shell Isolated
1.5) This is important for further debugging! Make a copy of the solution directory.
2) Right click solution-> Add->New Project...->C#->Editor Margin
3) In ShellExtensionsVSIX project open source.extension.vsixmanifest with a designer
4) Go to Assets->New
5) Type: Ms.VS.MefComponent, Source: a project in current solution, Project: [ditor margin project], OK->Save
6) In [editor margin project]->source.extension.vsixmanifest set publisher, Save
7) Run

Open a text file with isolated shell app. It should appear a nice green rectangle with "Hello World!" at the bottom of the text editor.

Close the application, and go back to visual studio.

1) Close the solution
2) Navigate to Documents and find a directory named after your solution. Delete it.
3) Go to Users/[username]/AppData/Microsoft/VisualStudio/11.0Exp/Extensions, remove cache files and all directories that are associated with the extension project (I deleted everything)
4) Open solution from the copy made before adding Editor Margin
5) Run the shell app and open a text file

Magic. Editor margin still works... Is it silently cached somewhere?

Best Regards